# All of my objects disappear in my iOS simulator, why is that?

Tags: ios, object, uiviewcontroller, xcode6, ios-simulator

I'm currently working with one navigation controller, and 3 view controllers. when i run my program, everything runs smooth, but none of my objects on my second and third view controller appear in the simulator ( labels, buttons, text fields etc.), how ever the navigation bar is there. why is that? how do i fix it?

Comment: You need to show the code for how you're going from your root view controller to the 2nd and 3rd ones . What troubleshooting have you done? Are the viewDidLoad methods in the 2nd and 3rd controllers being called?

Comment: You have changed the size class to something that isn't compatible with the device you are running on.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the issue was that I had added the button to the LaunchScreen.storyboard, instead of the Main.storyboard.

Credit to this post: http://discourse.djp3.net/t/first-ios-app-button-and-label-disappear-in-simulator/104/13?u=drazisil

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was an auto layout error. I removed auto layout and disabled size classes from my project and the simulator showed every object within the interface. I then enabled both auto layout and size classes once again & manually added my constraints instead of allowing Xcode to do it for me. Worked out fine once i ran the simulator again. I think this is a bug in Xcode's iOS sim.

Comment: No, it's not a bug or an auto layout error. It's just that the constraints Xcode adds for you might not be appropriate, especially when size classes is turned on -- that pseudo-controller is 600x600, so if you put anything too far to the right or bottom, it will be off screen on a real device. The automatically added constraints are always top, left, height, and width.